# Generate webservice from WSDL with Document/literal format

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, wsimport

I am having troubles generating a WS from a WSDL by means of wsimport.

The WSDL is the TMDD v3.0 standard specification (WSDL and related XSD files can be found [here](http://www.ite.org/standards/tmdd/TMDDv3.0%20wsdl%20schemas%20-%20Final.zip))

According to [this article from IBM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-whichwsdl/) the WSDL seems to be in Document/literal format.

In order to get the WSDL compiled I have created some bindings/tweaks however I am stuck at this error (it does not generate a method since the operation has more than one part):

```
[WARNING] Ingoring operation "DlFullEventUpdateSubscription": more than one part
 bound to body
  line 17 of file:/O:/temp/wsdltest/TMDD-stripped.wsdl
```

To simplify, this is the stripped down version of the WSDL with only the interesting operation definition

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns:tns="http://www.tmdd.org/3/dialogs"
    xmlns:tmdd="http://www.tmdd.org/3/messages" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:c2c="http://www.ntcip.org/c2c-message-administration" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    name="TMDDCenterServices" targetNamespace="http://www.tmdd.org/3/dialogs">
    <documentation>
    </documentation>
    <types>

        <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <xs:import namespace="http://www.tmdd.org/3/messages"
                schemaLocation="TMDD.xsd" />
            <xs:import namespace="http://www.ntcip.org/c2c-message-administration"
                schemaLocation="C2C.xsd" />
        </xs:schema>
    </types>
    <message name="MSG_EventSubscription">
        <part name="c2cMsgAdmin" element="c2c:c2cMessageSubscription" />
        <part name="message" element="tmdd:eventRequestMsg" />
    </message>
    <!-- Common Messages -->
    <message name="MSG_ConfirmationReceipt">
        <!-- CONNECTION MANAGEMENT Messages -->
        <part name="message" element="c2c:c2cMessageReceipt" />
    </message>
    <message name="MSG_ErrorReport">
        <part name="message" element="tmdd:errorReportMsg" />
    </message>
    <!-- TMDD Owner Center Porttype -->
    <portType name="tmddOCSoapHttpServicePortType">
        <operation name="DlFullEventUpdateSubscription">
            <documentation>
                <objectClass>Event</objectClass>
                <msgPattern>Sub</msgPattern>
                <requirement>REQ1261</requirement>
            </documentation>
            <input message="tns:MSG_EventSubscription" />
            <output message="tns:MSG_ConfirmationReceipt" />
            <fault name="errorReport" message="tns:MSG_ErrorReport" />
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <!-- TMDD Owner Center binding -->
    <binding name="tmddOCSoapHttpServiceBinding" type="tns:tmddOCSoapHttpServicePortType">
        <soap:binding style="document"
            transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
        <operation name="DlFullEventUpdateSubscription">
            <soap:operation soapAction="' '" style="document" />
            <input>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </output>
            <fault name="errorReport">
                <soap:fault name="errorReport" use="literal" />
            </fault>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    <!-- TMDD Owner Center Service -->
    <service name="tmddOCSoapHttpService">
        <!-- ************************ -->
        <!-- OWNER CENTER Services -->
        <!-- ************************ -->
        <port name="tmddOCSoapHttpServicePort" binding="tns:tmddOCSoapHttpServiceBinding">
            <soap:address location="http://tmdd.owner.center.com/c2cxml/" />
        </port>
    </service>
</definitions>
```

The bindings file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bindings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" version="2.1" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws">
    <!-- To create standalone classes instead of nested classes -->
    <!--<globalBindings localScoping="toplevel"/>-->

    <!--*****************-->
    <!-- Package Binding -->
    <!--*****************-->

    <!--*****************************-->
    <!-- C2C classes package binding -->
    <!--*****************************-->
    <bindings schemaLocation="C2C.xsd">
        <schemaBindings>
            <package name="tdf.tmdd.model.ntcip.messageadministration" />
        </schemaBindings>
    </bindings>

    <!--**************************************-->
    <!-- ITIS-Adopted classes package binding -->
    <!--**************************************-->
    <bindings schemaLocation="ITIS-Adopted-03-00-02.xsd">
        <schemaBindings>
            <package name="tdf.tmdd.model.itis.adopted" />
        </schemaBindings>       
    </bindings>

    <!--************************************-->
    <!-- ITIS-Local classes package binding -->
    <!--************************************-->
    <bindings schemaLocation="ITIS-Local-03-00-02.xsd">
        <schemaBindings>
            <package name="tdf.tmdd.model.itis.local" />
        </schemaBindings>
    </bindings>

    <!--**************************************-->
    <!-- LRMS-Adopted classes package binding -->
    <!--************************************* -->
    <bindings schemaLocation="LRMS-Adopted-02-00-00.xsd">
        <schemaBindings>
            <package name="tdf.tmdd.model.lrms.adopted" />
        </schemaBindings>                   
    </bindings>

    <!--************************************-->
    <!-- LRMS-Local classes package binding -->
    <!--************************************-->
    <bindings schemaLocation="LRMS-Local-02-00-00.xsd">
        <schemaBindings>
            <package name="tdf.tmdd.model.lrms.local" />
        </schemaBindings>
    </bindings>

    <!--*******************************-->
    <!-- NTCIP classes package binding -->
    <!--*******************************-->
    <bindings schemaLocation="NTCIP-References.xsd">
        <schemaBindings>
            <package name="tdf.tmdd.model.ntcip.objectreferences" />
        </schemaBindings>
    </bindings>

    <!--******************************-->
    <!-- TMDD classes package binding -->
    <!--******************************-->
    <bindings schemaLocation="TMDD.xsd">
        <schemaBindings>
            <package name="tdf.tmdd.model" />
        </schemaBindings>   
    </bindings>

    <!--***********************-->
    <!-- Class personalization -->
    <!--***********************-->

    <!--************************************-->
    <!-- LRMS-Adopted class personalization -->
    <!--************************************-->
    <bindings schemaLocation="LRMS-Adopted-02-00-00.xsd">
        <bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='Chain']//xs:sequence//xs:element[@name='chain']//xs:complexType">
            <class name="ChainElement" />
        </bindings>   
        <bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='GridPointPair']">
            <class name="GridPointPairAdopted" />
        </bindings>                 
        <bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='AreaLocation']">
            <class name="AreaLocationAdopted" />
        </bindings>    
        <bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='LinkLocation']">
            <class name="LinkLocationAdopted" />
        </bindings>
        <bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='AdminAreaGroup']">
            <class name="AdminAreaGroupAdopted" />
        </bindings>  
        <bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='GridPointSequence']">
            <class name="GridPointSequenceAdopted" />
        </bindings>  
        <bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='Grid']">
            <class name="GridAdopted" />
        </bindings>  
        <bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='NodeAttribute']">
            <class name="NodeAttributeAdopted" />
        </bindings>  
        <bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='GridPoint']">
            <class name="GridPointAdopted" />
        </bindings>       
    </bindings>

    <!--********************************-->
    <!-- factory method personalization -->
    <!--********************************-->

    <!--*************************************-->
    <!-- TMDD factory method personalization -->
    <!--*************************************-->
    <bindings schemaLocation="TMDD.xsd" >
        <bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='IntersectionSignalInventoryLinkList']">
             <factoryMethod name="createIntersectionSignalInventoryLinks" />
         </bindings>
    </bindings>
</bindings>
```

The command line to invoke wsimport is the following:

```
O:\temp\wsdltest>wsimport -extension -Xdebug -s src -b bindings.xjb TMDD-stripped.wsdl
```

What can I do to get the "DlFullEventUpdateSubscription" operation correctly created? Are there any alternatives to generate the Java web service? I can not modify the operation definition, since that would not comply with the standard.

**Update. Solution**

I managed to get it working by modifying WSDL so each part of the message is assigned to header and body:

```
<binding name="tmddOCSoapHttpServiceBinding" type="tns:tmddOCSoapHttpServicePortType">
    <soap:binding style="document"
        transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <operation name="DlFullEventUpdateSubscription">
        <soap:operation soapAction="' '" style="document" />
        <input>
            <soap:header message="tns:MSG_EventSubscription" use="literal" part="c2cMsgAdmin"/>
            <soap:body use="literal" parts="message"/>
        </input>
        <output>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </output>
        <fault name="errorReport">
            <soap:fault name="errorReport" use="literal" />
        </fault>
    </operation>
</binding>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Document-Literal cannot have multi-part message operations. You can use below alternatives.

- Use Document/Literal Wrapped style - Wrap multiple parts in a single
  document.
- Use RPC/Literal style - No restrictions on binding multiple
  parts in soap body.

Thanks,
Sreehari.

Comment: How would you configure any of those alternatives in wsdl? Thanks

Comment: Put c2cMessageSubscription and eventRequestMsg in another element.   `<root>
 <c2cMessageSubscription>...</c2cMessageSubscription>
 <eventRequestMsg>...</eventRequestMsg>
</root>` then add "root" as only part of MSG_EventSubscription.