# Unable to convert wsdl to java using wsimport - more than one part bound to body

Tags: java, wsdl, cxf, wsdl2java, wsimport

Command -(i tried other tools also,  cxf gives- same below mentioned error and axis2 - says this wsdl is in ws rpc std. so can not convert)

wsimport -B-XautoNameResolution -Xdebug -XdisableAuthenticator    -keep -s /Users/mukesh/Desktop  http://airarabia.isaaviations.com/webservices/services/AAResWebServices?wsdl

WSDL - http://airarabia.isaaviations.com/webservices/services/AAResWebServices?wsdl

Error -

```
[ERROR] operation "modifyReservation": more than one part bound to body
  line 4663 of http://airarabia.isaaviations.com/webservices/services/AAResWebServices?wsdl

Exception in thread "main" com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wscompile.AbortException
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModelerBase.error(WSDLModelerBase.java:732)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.setMessagePartsBinding(WSDLModeler.java:1505)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.setMessagePartsBinding(WSDLModeler.java:1431)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.processLiteralSOAPOperation(WSDLModeler.java:767)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.processSOAPOperation(WSDLModeler.java:698)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.processPort(WSDLModeler.java:466)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.processService(WSDLModeler.java:245)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.internalBuildModel(WSDLModeler.java:216)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.buildModel(WSDLModeler.java:126)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.buildWsdlModel(WsimportTool.java:429)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.run(WsimportTool.java:190)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.run(WsimportTool.java:168)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.Invoker.invoke(Invoker.java:159)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.WsImport.main(WsImport.java:42)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate webservice from WSDL with Document/literal format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10597270/generate-webservice-from-wsdl-with-document-literal-format)